# OGNL class keyword handling

Tags: ognl

I would like to translate this java code to OGNL code:

```
SomeClass.class.getDeclaredFields()
```

I tried in OGNL:

```
@SomeClass.class@getDeclaredFields()
```

but I got

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to resolve class: SomeClass.class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [getDeclaredFields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredField(java.lang.String)) is not static. So it needs "."(dot).

For class use @ as it would be static field.

Use

```
@SomeClass@class.getDeclaredFields()
```